# Linux command to replace set of lines for a group of files under a directory

Tags: linux, unix, sed, file-handling

I need to replace first 4 header lines of only selected 250 erlang files (with extension .erl), but there are 400 erlang files in total in the directory+subdirectories, I need to avoid modifying the files which doesn't need the change.
I've the list of file names that are to be modified, but don't know how to make my linux command to make use of them.

```
sed -i '1s#.*#%% This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public#' *.erl
sed -i '2s#.*#%% License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this file,#' *.erl
sed -i '3s#.*#%% You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.#' *.erl
sed -i '4s#.*##' *.erl
```

in the above commands instead of passing *.erl I want to pass those list of file names which I need to modify, doing that one by one will take me more than 3 days to complete it.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the shortlisted file names using `awk` and use `xargs` to execute the `sed`. You can execute multiple `sed` commands to a file using `-e` option.

```
awk '{print $1}' your_shortlisted_file_lists  | xargs sed -i -e first_sed -e second_sed $1
```

`xargs` gets the file name from `awk` in a `$1` variable.

Comment: Maybe emphasize that the four `sed` scripts can and should be combined into a single script.

Comment: @tripleee, yes that is an better approach. Also if it has come down to script, we can also iterate over the files using `for loop` and execute the `sed's`

Comment: @EdMorton, it will print the first token of each line

Comment: OK and how is that useful? You don't think the `$1` at the end of the sed script is the same `$1` as used in the awk command do you? Best I can tell the only thing the awk command is doing compared to, say, `cat your_shortlisted_file_lists` is breaking the script if any of the file names contain spaces but that'd be a UUOC anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
< file_list.txt xargs -1 sed -i -e 'first_cmd' -e 'second_cmd' ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Not answering your question but a suggestion for improvement.  Four `sed` commands for replacing header is inefficient.  I would instead write the new header into a file and do the following

```
sed -i -e '1,3d' -e '4{r header' -e 'd}' file
```

will replace the first four lines of the file with header.

Another concern with your current `s###` approach is you have to watch for special chars `\`, `&` and your delimiter `#` in the text you are replacing.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the sed `c` (for change) command to each file of your list :

```
while read file; do
  sed -i '1,4 c\
%% This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public\
%% License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this file,\
%% You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.\

' "$file"
done < filelist
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a file called `file_list.txt` with all file names as content:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
```

You can simply read all lines into a variable (here: `files`) and then iterate through each one:

```
files=`cat file_list.txt`
for file in $files; do
   echo "do something with $file"
done
```

Comment: With some minor syntactic changes, this is doable in Bash as well.  In particular, use `"${files[@]}"` to obtain a list of the members in the array `files`.

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for the correct way to write that loop IF its ever necessary.